# Struggling with reading selected text from a txt file

Tags: c#

I have a text file called `reports.txt` that I am able to get to open on `Rich Text` but is there any way that I can get it to open but only display *selected text*

The file contains

```
CPU Score: 322
CPU General: 708473
CPU Targeted: 341030088
RAM Score: 135
RAM Size (MB): 4001
RAM Speed (MB/s): 12144
GPU Compute (GFLOPS): 181
Disk Score: 49
Disk Write (MB/s): 117
Disk Read (MB/s): 322
```

For example, I would like it to display `322, 135, 49` in like a `TextBox`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible and simple:

```
void Main()
{
    var dict = File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\yourFolder\yourFile.txt")
    .Select(f => f.Split(':'))
    .Select(f => new {
        Name=f[0].Trim(),
        Value=f[1].Trim()
    })
    .ToDictionary(f => f.Name, f=>f.Value);

    Console.WriteLine($"{dict["CPU Score"]}, {dict["RAM Score"]}, {dict["Disk Score"]}" );
}
```

Comment: If the format was guaranteed to be as he posted, you could even do `Value=int.Parse(f[1].Trim())`, which might have more utility if the data is ever needed outside of displaying.

Comment: @ParrishHusband, sorry I don't understand what do you mean. Parse to int and then back to string to display in textbox? Without parsing it is more straight forward. If you would parse I suggest TryParse instead.

Comment: In the exact example OP provided your answer is perfect, hence my upvote.  I was adding on that if they ever needed the int value for something other than displaying, it could be done with a parse if the data was safe.

Comment: @ParrishHusband, I see. Honestly, that was what I was writing originally, but regretted thinking his purpose. Once he have the values he can do whatever he likes to. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah impossible to tell without seeing more from OP.  I was thinking it could be a UI for comparing or graphing PC scores, which he might need the int for.  Either way I think you've covered the major part of the question.

Comment: Thank you for your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Cetin Basoz

Heres the code, that you help me with. I Just need to get it to add it all together now for the total score :)

```
        private void novabnt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var dict = File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\source\reports.txt")
        .Select(f => f.Split(':'))
        .Select(f => new
        {
            Name = f[0].Trim(),
            Value = f[1].Trim()
        })
        .ToDictionary(f => f.Name, f => f.Value);

        txtrams.Text = String.Empty;
        txtrams.AppendText(dict["RAM Score"]);
        txtCPUS.Text = String.Empty;
        txtCPUS.AppendText(dict["CPU Score"]);
        txthdds.Text = String.Empty;
        txthdds.AppendText(dict["Disk Score"]);
        txttotals.Text = String.Empty;
```

[Photo of C# program running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBRDP.png)

In the end I am going to get it to run a program that creates these scores and updates the text file then runs this command.

Comment: I assume this is not a question. If it is then you would do int.Parse(dict["CPU Score"]) + int.Parse(dict["RAM Score"]) + int.Parse(dict["Disk Score"])